# Rauc-Hawkbit-Updater cant connect to hawkBit

Tags: eclipse-hawkbit, hawkbit

I successfully deployed rauc-hawkbit-updater. But when I try to run it, it always get a `401 Unauthorized` Error. I used following config file:

```
[client]
hawkbit_server            = 192.168.10.29:8080
ssl                       = false
ssl_verify                = false
tenant_id                 = DEFAULT
target_name               = Testgeraet
bundle_download_location  = /tmp/bundle.raucb
auth_token                = 59717ebd8df47764e7a29e742e2b4c63

[device]
key1                      = valueA
key2                      = valueB
```

The auth_token is the same one, as in the hawkBit Server:

[image: Testgeraet in hawkBit Server]

I also activated the needed Settings from the Server:

[image: Server config]

But all the Server returnes is an error:

[image: Server error]

The Header is set properly:

[image: Header]

I am stuck at this problem. Do you know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled about the Solution. In the target_name I have to insert the Controller ID.